# AngularJS body function randomly going off

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I'm trying to accomplish is the body background being set to a random image on page load. I have tried both a service and a controller function.

The issue is that this works, but if I do anything like tooltips, click buttons, or even open inspector on the page, the method gets fired again.

Currently:

```
app.service('getBodyStyle', function () {
  var bgs = [ 
    //list of jpgs
  ]
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * bgs.length);
  var bg   = bgs[rand];

  return { "background": "linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url('./Images/"+bg+"') no-repeat center center fixed" };
});
```

and the html:

```
body layout="column" ng-style="getBodyStyle()" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
```

Comment: Using a function for `ngStyle` is just terrible!!! It will calculate on every digest loop

Comment: How would you do it instead?

Comment: Controller that save the result of `getBodyStyle()` to one of the scope properties (`$scope.bodyStyle = getBodyStyle()`) and replacing the view with `ng-style="bodyStyle"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When any model in view is updated the app refreshes the view.

Use a variable to store the result of your function.

```
<body layout="column" ng-style="bodystyle" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
```

or allow the service to remember the last result:

```
app.service('getBodyStyle', function () {
  var self = this;

  if (!self.bg)
  {
      var bgs = [ 
        //list of jpgs
      ]
      var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * bgs.length);
      var bg   = bgs[rand];

      self.bg = { "background": "linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url('./Images/"+bg+"') no-repeat center center fixed" };
  }
  return self.bg;
});
```

Comment: In your `AppCtrl` define a `$scope.bodystyle` and assign it a value on controller initialization. Your controllers can run functions, but you have to expose them to the view.

Answer (score 0):

The method is going to get called every time a digest cycle runs, which happens... a lot. I would suggest injecting the service into your `AppController`, setting the result to an object on your scope/controller, and then accessing that object from the `ng-style`.

Answer (score 0):

You should just set ng-style to be a scope property, and trigger the method only at controller activation. And move the list of jpgs to a configuration constant on the app module.
If the functionality is used elsewhere, then keep it as a service and inject it to the controller. Then use it in the getBodyStyle controller method.

```
(function () {
    angular.module ("app")
        .controller ("bodyController", bodyController);

    bodyController.$inject = [/* deps */];

    function bodyController (/* deps */) {
          var vm = this;

          vm.backgroundStyle = "";

          activate ();

          function activate() {
               getBodyStyle();
          }

          function getBodyStyle() {
               //....
               vm.backgroundStyles = styles;
          }
    }
})();


<body ng-controller="bodyController as vm" ng-style="vm.backgroundStyle">
```

Comment: If the list of images comes from an API method, it might be good to keep it as a service. Having the list cached in the service would be good for business in this case as well.

Comment: Indeed, I used my imagination as to what the requirement could evolve into. Tomorrow his boss, or partner, or wife might say "Hey! Let's make the random image list specific to the user. How long would that take?"

Comment: Yeah, the life of a programmer!